# Spring boot 3 Upgrade Issue with API response

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, gson, spring-boot-3

I am upgrading my current spring boot 2.6.7 to spring boot 3.1.4. I have updated all the dependencies and re-imported all required packages as well. it is a multi-tenant application.

I am using the Postgres database. to get query results in JSON format I am writing native queries in the below format

```
select Row_to_json(list) as response, row_number() over() as id from (
select * from sch.employees )list
```

Below is the code to extract results from the entitymanager to the required format.

> ```
> public <T> Optional<List<T>> getResultList(String[] parametersName, Object[] parametersValues, Class<T> klazz,
>           String queryString) {
>       try {
>           Query nativeQuery = em.createNativeQuery(queryString, NativeQueryResponse.class);
>           for (int i = 0; i < parametersName.length; i++) {
>               nativeQuery.setParameter(parametersName[i], parametersValues[i]);
>           }
>           List<NativeQueryResponse<T>> details = nativeQuery.getResultList();
>           Type typeOfT = TypeToken.getParameterized(List.class, klazz).getType();
>
>           List<T> response;
>           if (!details.isEmpty() && details.get(0).getResponse() instanceof List) {
>               response = (List<T>) details.get(0).getResponse();
>           } else {
>               response = details.stream().map(NativeQueryResponse::getResponse)
>                       .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
>           }
>
>           em.clear();
>           return Optional.of(gson.fromJson(gson.toJson(response), typeOfT));
>       } catch (Exception e) {
>           log.error("error while executing query {} with parameters as {} and parameters values as {} ", queryString,
>                   parametersName, parametersValues);
>           CommonUtils.printStackTrack(e);
>           return Optional.empty();
>       }
>   }
> ```

It is returning data also and finally mapping same to required object as well. Below is
class to which it is mapping.

```
public class NativeQueryResponse<T> {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Type(JsonType.class)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
    T response;

}
```

It is creating list of employee object as well. below my class to be deserialised.

```
@Setter
@Getter
public class Employee {
    
    @SerializedName(value = "id")
    private Long id;

    @SerializedName(value = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @SerializedName(value = "middle_name")
    private String middleName;

    @SerializedName(value = "dob")
    private String dob;
}
```

Even at controller layer also i can see list of employee with its every property filled up with data but while returning response, it is not sending response in java properties defined ,instead it is sending response in what i have defined as serializedName

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "first_name": "User 1",
    "middle_name": "M name",
    "dob": ""
}
```

Expected is

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "firstName": "User 1",
    "middleName": "M name",
    "dob": ""
}
```

I even have gone through [github link](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/2137) that say's to define

> spring.http.converters.preferred-json-mapper: gson

but even after that also it is still returning API response in property what i defined for SerialisedName or just like that we are returning from database query.

Below is current spring security updates in application

> ```
> @Bean
>   SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
>       http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable).authorizeHttpRequests(
>               request -> request.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll().requestMatchers("/**").permitAll())
>               .sessionManagement(manager -> manager.sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS))
>               .addFilterBefore(new AuthenticationFilter(environment), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
>       return http.build();
>   }
> ```

few more config details for more analysis.

```
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <project.reports.dir>${basedir}/target/reports</project.reports.dir>
        <java.version>20</java.version>
        <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
        <json-path.version>2.4.0</json-path.version>
        <org.projectlombok.version>1.18.24</org.projectlombok.version>
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.5.5.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
        <log4j2.version>2.17.0</log4j2.version>
```

I am not sure where is the exact issue. every API is behaving this way But if I use JPA repository to get data in API , they are returning result properly.this issue is only when I am deserializing using GSON.

please advice if the above implementation seems to be incorrect or not properly implemented as part of best practices.

Comment: This appears to be working exactly as it should.  When you applied `@SerializedName(value = "first_name")` to the field `firstName`, it correctly serializes as `first_name`, which is precisely what it should be doing.

Comment: @lane.maxwell before upgrading , it was returning as firstName only

Comment: @lane.maxwell Every API behaves this way But if I use JPA repository to get data in the API , they return results properly. this issue is only when I am deserializing using GSON.

Comment: You're confusing getting an Object from a database with the serialization of that object; they're entirely separate.  Your ORM returns a list of Employees; then your serializer serializes that based on the properties you've specified.  You've explicitly told your serializer to write the field `firstName` as `first_name`.  If it worked before, it was doing so because it was probably using the native ObjectMapper and not your gson serializer.  As your code is written and given the response, it's doing exactly what you've told it to.

Comment: @lane.maxwell the native query is returning data in java.util.LinkedHashMap , I am using gson to convert this to Java Object and returning as API response. my ORM using native query is returning List<java.util.LinkedHashMap> , earlier also it was working exactly same.  i am not sure if I understood you completely.

Comment: It's a List, but ultimately that list contains a type of Object, in this case, it's Employee.  I believe your serializer is functioning correctly, as it's serializing the fields the way that it's been instructed to do.  On a side note, this looks a little suspect too, `gson.fromJson(gson.toJson(response)`, because `f −1(f (x))` is just `x`.

Comment: @RanveerSinghRajpurohit something that might help you debug this is to inspect the output of `gson.toJson(response)`

Answer (score 1):

Your serializer is doing precisely what you've asked it to do.  You don't even need to consider all the logic that leads up to a list of employees being created; all you need to know is that you have a list of employees that aren't serializing the way that you think they should be.

Consider this test

```
@Test
public void testIt() {
    List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
    employees.add(Employee.builder().firstName("bob").middleName("middle bob").build());
    employees.add(Employee.builder().firstName("bill").middleName("middle bill").build());

    Assertions.assertEquals("[{\"firstName\":\"bob\",\"middleName\":\"middle bob\"},{\"firstName\":\"bill\",\"middleName\":\"middle bill\"}]", new Gson().toJson(employees));
}
```

If you run this now, it will fail with

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expected :[{"firstName":"bob","middleName":"middle bob"},{"firstName":"bill","middleName":"middle bill"}]
Actual   :[{"first_name":"bob","middle_name":"middle bob"},{"first_name":"bill","middle_name":"middle bill"}]
```

Now, remove those annotations that you have on your Employee class that specifically tell the serializer to serialize `firstName` as `first_name` and `middleName` as `middle_name` and run the test again.  This time your test will pass.

Your serialization is working precisely as you have instructed it to.  If in your previous implementation it was serializing firstName as firstName even though you had the `SerializedName` set to `first_name`, then it's because you had an error in your previous version.

Comment: if I use ObjectMapper and use @JsonAlias({ "first_name" }) in the POJO class , it is properly returning firstName as API response, that's where I am confused where is error actually ? it is not an entity class , it just like projections , I am executing native queries , getting LinkedHashMap and then using these library to convert them to Java Object and sending as API response. i am doing these for only get api's

Comment: `JsonAlias` is a jackson specific annotation, meaning that if you have configured GSON to be the underlying mapper, then its going to ignore those annotations. You are clearly mixing up GSON annotations and Jackson annotations and then not knowing what is in a later stage acctually being used to serialize/deserialize. Lanes answer is completely correct here.